# Replace brooks with streams in dwarf fortress

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Is there any way I can create a dwarf fortress world with no brooks, or at least fewer of them? Some specific settings in worldgen, maybe? I like to use bridges as chokepoints, and the streams as barriers to invaders, but it's very difficult to find a good embark site with anything other than a brook.

Comment: You can always dig channel in the brooks to make them impassable, if you want.

Comment: @Jupotter I do that eventually, but it's usually a little while before I have miners free to work on that. Besides, it's fun having to create bridges with my starting seven to get to where I want to make the fortress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [DF Wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/v0.31:Advanced_world_generation), rivers need a fair bit of elevation (300 and up) and rainfall to form. Creating a world with high elevation and rainfall will result in more rivers. The article has quite a bit of info on creating worlds with custom parameters.

A bit of terraforming could also go a long way. A moat is an excellent way to prevent attackers from hugging the walls, making sure they are at the optimal angle for marksdwarves behind elevated fortifications. Carving a fortification into the map edge should allow for infinite drainage, so you can still have moving water in your artificial river.

Comment: I generally do something similar, except I make a branch that goes through a tunnel under my fortress, so the fortress has well access. I'll have to try genning a world with higher rainfall, see how well that works to give me bigger water features in the mountains.